# Grouping consecutive months together for categorizing data in HIVE

Tags: group-by, hive, hiveql

I wish to group my data for consecutive groups of months to get an overview of a trend.

The data is like this:

[image]

The required(output) grouping will be as follows:

[image]

Here, I want to have the values only when there is a proper grouping present for 3 consecutive months(this can be varied like 2 or 4 consecutive months), but no case scenarios when there is any month values missing from the data.

**For Example**: user 1 has values in the month of 2018-01 but there is no grouping available in the final required output for this month, as there is no value present for 2017-11 to 2018-01 or 2017-12 to 2018-02 or 2018-01 to 2018-03 to group this month.

Comment: What is the type of "month"?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . here is one way that checks if there are three consecutive months and then returns the sum:

```
select user, month, month_2, value_3
from (select t.*,
             lead(month, 2) over (partition by user order by month) as month_2,
             (sum(value) +
              lead(value) over (partition by user order by month) +
              lead(value, 2) over (partition by user order by month)
             ) as value_3
      from t
     ) t
where month_2 = add_months(month, 2);
```